# How to use value from NgFor in Angular2 on the very same tag?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I need to be able to do a loop in a template and use value from the data on the same tag I'm doing `*ngFor`. Like this:

```
<a *ngFor="#language of Settings.allLanguages" id="language-link-{{language.id}}">
        {{language.name}}
</a>
```

But it gives error:

`Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known native property`

(If I leave only the loop code in the tag markup - it works fine:

```
<a *ngFor="#language of Settings.allLanguages">
        {{language.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the code that causes the error. It looks like you are binding to `[value]="..."` somewhere. We need to see this code instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this works. Which version of the Angular 2 Beta are you using?

Comment: The version is angular.2.0.0-beta.7

Comment: This works. Update your version. @peshohristov

Comment: `*ngFor="#item of items"` syntax is [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1) as of 2.0.0-beta.17. Update and use the `let item of items` syntax instead.

Comment: damn ... I did a plunker and it worked there :D ... http://plnkr.co/edit/hOkUItxKKEaTES7DV62U?p=preview ... ... ... I will research more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have code like

```
[value]="xxx"
```

while it should be

```
[att.value]="xxx"
```

or instead of

```
value="{{xxx}}"
```

use

```
att.value="{{xxx}}"
```

Comment: I'm not using anything like [...] ... all the bindings in the template are done with double curly brackets - {{...}}.

Comment: Hard to tell because your question doesn't contain the code that causes the error. I updated my answer.

Comment: Off ... I was wrong :D ... I've been trying to use data attribute (data-value) and that's what was causing the problem. Pointing it as `attr.data-value` solved the problem. (Just never thought I wont' be able to use normal plain data attributes any more :( ...)

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out. You actually got an error message about `'value'` even though you bound to `data-value`?

Comment: Yes. `<a data-value="{{language.id}}">{{language.name}}</a>` produced error, while `<a attr.data-value="{{language.id}}">{{language.name}}</a>` was OK.